# How to set transaction timeout in HikariCP

Tags: spring, jooq, hikaricp

I am looking for an analog of the `setDefaultTimeout` method of Spring's `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` in jOOQ/HikariCP connection pool.

I found various timeouts like `loginTimeout`, `maxLifetime`, and `idleTimeout` in `HikariDataSource`, but none of them seems to fit my purpose.

I looked at jOOQ's `TransactionProvider` too.

After some source code investigation I spotted the following code in HikariCP:

```
         setNetworkTimeout(connection, validationTimeout);

         try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            if (isNetworkTimeoutSupported != TRUE) {
               setQueryTimeout(statement, 
                   (int) MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(
                       Math.max(1000L, validationTimeout)));
            }

            statement.execute(config.getConnectionTestQuery());
         }
```

Looking at this, I suppose the configuration I am after is `validationTimeout`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have found is to run connection validation query (normally very quick) where it is applying 'validation timeout'.

Most probably, transaction in 'your app' will take much longer than validation timeout specified for HikariCP

at present, you can set query time out for org.jooq.Query but not for org.jooq.Routine. see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3892

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing AbstractPlatformTransactionManager I am guessing that you wish to use transactions which expressing your queries using JOOQ on top of a HikariCP connection pool.

The best place to start maybe JOOQ's transaction documentation here

```
http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/
```

As you are coming from Spring, the Spring TX integration maybe a good starting place.

HikariCP does not itself provide timeout management as it focuses on just managing the connections that it has formed. As such the 3 values you have listed do very different things

loginTimeout - how long HikariCP will wait for a connection to be formed to the database (basically a JDBC connection)

maxLifetime  - how long a connection will live in the pool before being closed

idleTimeout  - how long an unused connection lives in the pool